# Do I use appositive clause correctly?

Tags: sentence-construction, appositives

Can I use appositive clause (in bold) in the following way:

> The merits of technology should never be denied, **that they eliminate the inconvenience of attending events in person, be it traffic congestions or clash in schedule.**

I want to use a appositive clause to help explain what is the merits of technology, is this the acceptable way to do that?

Comment: No, because clauses can't function as appositives; only noun phrases can.

Answer (score 1):

I would think an [appositive clause](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/appositive/) would follow a noun. As for your sentence I would reformulate it in this way:

> The merits of technology in eliminating the inconvenience of attending events in person, be it traffic congestions or clash in schedule, should never be denied.

Comment: appreciate your answer. One follow-up question is that does "the merits" count as a noun preceding the appositive clause, though seperated by other components of the main sentence?

Comment: no, not really. If you check the link I included in my answer, you will understand how appositions work. They usually follow the noun, immediately and commas are used before and after them. They are usually noun phrases.

Comment: But clauses can't function as appositives; only noun phrases can.

Comment: Yet I found this expression used [here](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/85127-appositive-clause). But I understand what you mean. I am not very familiar with English grammar terms.